# selenium.keyUpNative()

Tags: java, selenium

I need to close a lightbox by pressing escape key.

Since my app and selenium rc reside on different ips,

```
selenium.keyUpNative("27")
```

doesn't work as intended. Is there any such event in selenium that works on remote machine?